# How to match the data found in the "Sharing Hierarchy" view?

Tags: sharing

If I query the `AccountShare` table to find the sharing reasons for a particular `Account` record, then I get a single row returned with a `RowCause` of `Owner` and a `UserOrGroupId` of the owner's ID.

I assumed this would account for *all* of the users that could access that record.

However, when I use the "Share Hierarchy" button to view that record's access, I see it has also shows another couple of rows for users that can access the record because they are Administrators.

Is there a reason that this sharing reason isn't returned by `AccountShare`?

To emulate the same sharing view, I would have to also query the user table to get a list of administrators as well, I suppose?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the "Administrator" reason for access is shown when a user has either "View All" or "Modify All" access to a given SObject.

This will have been applied either in their profile, or via a permission set.